# What is the "last" data that get's backed up, when running pg_dump on a live server?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm wondering: If I start doing a pg_dump of a very large database (it would take hours), that is still running actively receiving writes, what is then the last data that goes into the backup? Is it:

1. The data as-it-was, at the point in time where the pg_dump command was initiated.
2. The last changes that it encountered at some point where it was dumping that individual record.
3. Something else.

Bonus question: If I'm trying to dump a database as part of trying to rescue it from corrupt data, will it then make any difference whether I use the `directory` format or the `custom` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the data at the start of the command for an entire database. According to the [manpage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html):

> It makes **consistent backups** even if the database is being used
>   concurrently. pg_dump does not block other users accessing the
>   database (readers or writers).

and in [SQL Dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html):

> Dumps created by pg_dump are internally consistent, meaning, the dump
>   represents a snapshot of the database at the time pg_dump began
>   running

Dumping in parallel (`--jobs`) may be problematic with changing data, but only when targeting less recent versions:

> For a consistent backup, the database server needs to support
>   synchronized snapshots, a feature that was introduced in PostgreSQL
>   9.2

I don't think the output format makes any difference in the rescue operation. Note that for a parallel dump, `directory` is the only possible format.